# can't view Wordpress Content in ionic App

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework

I'm new in ionic
and I have connected ionic app with wordpress website built with "wpbakery" page builder using rest api but i have a problem :
While i am trying to view this code in my app

```
<div>
  {{ info.content.rendered }}
</div>
```

This content just show HTML tags like this is screenshot

[image]

How i can fix that?

Comment: I don't know about ionic, but I know wordpress and you need to import bakery's CSS in order to display the page.

Comment: @Skatox Even if I imported Wpb CSS , how this will fix my problem , the content comes from JSON "Wp Rest Api" ?

Comment: `<div [innerHTML]="info.content.rendered"></div>` this is render your content ass html. Also use DOM Sanitizer to render HTMl correctly.